# Javascript arrays with html select list

Tags: javascript

I have a select list that goes from 0-4 and when selecting  a  number, it will output the name in the array. Instead of when selecting the number 1 and getting the ouput "Adam", i just get "Ron" for every number.

```js
friends = new Array('Alex', 'Adam', 'Jake', 'Cydney', 'Ron');

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function() {

  var nameSelected = document.getElementById('index').value;

  oneArrayValue = friends[0];

  oneArrayValue = friends[1];

  oneArrayValue = friends[2];

  oneArrayValue = friends[3];

  oneArrayValue = friends[4];

  document.getElementById('result').value = nameSelected;

};
```

```html
<body>
  <select id='number' name=''>
            <option value = '0'>0</option>
            <option value = '1'>1</option>
            <option value = '2'>2</option>
            <option value = '3'>3</option>
            <option value = '4'>4</option>
            <option value = '5'>5</option>
        </select>
  <button id='go' class=''>GO</button>
  <input id='result' name='' value='' class=''>
  <script src='js/javascript 07.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: please post the html also

Comment: Where do you get `"Ron"`? Whatever you output doesn’t have any connection to the `friends` array. You HTML doesn’t include an element with the ID `index`.

Comment: I guess there is still some relevant code you haven't posted yet. Where is `oneArrayValue` declared and why the hell are you overriding it starting with `friends[0]` til `friends[0]` (being Ron) - are you trying to use it as collection/list? You don't use that value later on, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
friends = new Array('Alex','Adam','Jake','Cydney','Ron');
/*
    you can even declare using the following:  
  
    friends = ['Alex','Adam','Jake','Cydney','Ron']; // <- this
*/

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {
    var nameSelected = document.getElementById('number').value;

    // getting the name from the index selected
    oneArrayValue = friends[nameSelected];
    document.getElementById('result').value = oneArrayValue;
};
```

```html
    <select id = 'number' name = ''>

        <option value = '0'>0</option>
        <option value = '1'>1</option>
        <option value = '2'>2</option>
        <option value = '3'>3</option>
        <option value = '4'>4</option>
        <option value = '5'>5</option>
    </select>
    <button id = 'go' class = ''>GO</button>
    <input id = 'result' name = '' value = '' class = ''>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you keep overwriting `oneArrayValue` so that only the last assignment sticks. Not to mention that `oneArrayValue` doesn't even seem to be declared in your code.

This is actually much simpler than what you are doing:

```js
// Here's the sligtly simpler "Array Literal" syntax for making an array
var friends = ['Alex','Adam','Jake','Cydney','Ron'];

// Use the modern, standards-based approach to event binding, not `onclick`, etc.
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener("click", function () {
  // Get the value out of the select
  var nameSelected = document.getElementById('number').value;
  // Set the content of the output area to the corresponding index element:
  document.getElementById('result').textContent = friends[nameSelected];
});
```

```html
<select id = 'number' name = ''>
  <option value = '0'>0</option>
  <option value = '1'>1</option>
  <option value = '2'>2</option>
  <option value = '3'>3</option>
  <option value = '4'>4</option>
  <option value = '5'>5</option>
</select>

<button id = 'go' class = ''>GO</button>

<!-- If you are just outputting a value, don't use a form element. -->
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not coded as the you expect result, see working code below

```js
friends = new Array('Alex','Adam','Jake','Cydney','Ron');

document.getElementById('go').onclick = function () {

var nameSelected = document.getElementById('index').value;

oneArrayValue = friends[nameSelected];
 
document.getElementById('result').value = oneArrayValue;

};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="result">
<select id="index">
<option val="0">0</option>
<option val="1">1</option>
<option val="2">2</option>
<option val="3">3</option>
<option val="4">4</option>
</select>




<input type="button" value="go" id="go" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to achieve something like this:

```js
var friends = ['Alex', 'Adam', 'Jake', 'Cydney', 'Ron'];

document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var idx = parseInt(document.getElementById('index').value);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = friends[idx];
});
```

```html
<select id="index">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Go" id="go" />
<div id="result"></div>
```